# Is this check for a date time field correct?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm wondering if I'm using date/time fields correctly in the vb part of access. 
I have a date time field where for example 14th april 2016 is standing.
If the "Dauer" which is duration in seconds is > 6 hours then something should happen else something else.

Datum and Dauer are variables directly assigned via sql statement (select) from a table. Then I use both of them (DAtum is of type Date/Time and Dauer of type int).

```
 If (Datum >= "16.07.2015" And Dauer > (6 * 60 * 60)) Then   ' 6 Stunden
```

Like mentioned above I have the case that with 14th april 2016 and duration > 6 hours (6.19 for example). But somehow I still end up in the else part of the if so I'm guessing either I did something wrong with the "Datum" variable or I have a problem in between the assignement and the if (although I wouldn't see anything).

Thus my question is do I check the date/time field correctly this way? So that only >= 16th of July 2015 it is checked if Dauer is greater than 6 hours?

Answer (score 0):

It is best to explicitly convert your comparison value to a DateTime value, using `CDate()` or `DateSerial()`.

For `CDate()`, the string should be either in US format (mm/dd/yyyy) or in ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd).

```
If Datum >= CDate("2015-07-16")
```

`DateSerial()` is best if your comparison date is variable as well, but can also be used with constants.

```
If Datum >= DateSerial(2015, 7, 16)
```

Comment: so it could be a conversion problem in reality? (thus that he converts it not always correctly?)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should provide the values to compare to as variables or constants of data type Date:

```
Dim CheckDatum As Date
Dim CheckDauer As Date
CheckDatum = DateSerial(2015, 7, 16) 
CheckDauer = TimeSerial(6, 0, 0)     

' or:

Const CheckDatum As Date = #07/16/2015#
Const CheckDauer As Date = #06:00:00#
```

Then

```
If Datum >= CheckDatum And Dauer > CheckDatum Then 

' or:

If DateDiff("d", CheckDatum, Datum) >= 0 And DateDiff("s", CheckDauer, Dauer) > 0 Then
```